# Removing Sign Up from top.link

Tags: magento-1.8, xml, toplinks

So my website currently has a "Register" button and a "Sign Up" button.  The "Sign Up" button doesn't show up on mobile devices no matter what, so I figure removing it is my best option.  I can remove "Register" successfully, but again, mobile view wouldn't have either one then.

I've checked and tested in two files: 
`local.xml` and `customer.xml`

For `local.xml` I tried commenting out the following `reference`:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink"
                ifconfig="ultimo/header/signup" translate="label title"><label>Sign Up</label><url>customer/account/create</url><title>Sign Up</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>101</position><liParams>id="link-sign-up"</liParams></action>
        </reference>

    </customer_logged_out>
```

Which unfortunately did nothing. (I'm saving these in my custom theme, not in `/base/default` directory)

In `customer.xml` and `local.xml` I've tried removing it by adding the following `removeLinkByUrl`:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
       <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/> </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Please point me in the right direction!

Comment: please commit also  /base/default directory

Comment: I am not getting u need to remove Signup right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what I needed to do. 
In the `customer.xml` I added the following code within `<customer_logged_out>`

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Register</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Not sure why I didn't think of this before..

This added the Register button back, and it doesn't disappear when the browser resolution is mobile sized.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from code also from admin setting:

From your question **ifconfig="ultimo/header/signup"**

Go to theme setting header section there may be signup enable/disable setting.

Second way using code:

Go to your mobile theme local.xml

```
<default>
  <reference name="top.links"> 
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
      <url helper="customer/account/create" />
    </action> 
  </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: My theme is Ultimo, so there's no setting to remove it. Also, it's responsive so there's no actual mobile theme. The "Sign Up" button just isn't there when the screen gets past a certain resolution, but the "Register" is.